# Google Chrome Developer Tools - disable black emulation options ruler

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, rulers

In Google Chrome version 38+, there's a new black ruler with Device emulation options.  Does anyone know how to disable this?

[image: ruler and emulation options]

Answer (score 334, accepted):

You can hide it by toggling the "Device Mode" button. I'm on Chrome 38 on OSX if that matters.

Note that the rulers will still show up if you need to do Device emulation.

[image]

This is from the Chrome Developer docs: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Can you emulate without this big fat black header?

Comment: Any way to spoof the user-agent without enabling all of the device emulation crap?

Comment: @devios There is a Chrome add-on I use called "Agent Spoofer" that you could try out.

Comment: I turned this on completely by accident trying to switch profiles in Chrome. Looks like I had the wrong window focused. Why oh why would they reuse a shortcut between the browser and devtools?

Comment: thanks. I got used to reopen the tab everytime until I saw this answer. A simple tiny close icon in the black ruler would also been suffice!!

Answer (score 1):

In version 44+:

In the main Dev tool window, click on the kebob menu and then Toggle device Toolbar.