# How do I disable the Chrome DevTools device emulator?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Since recent updates, Chrome DevTools now shows a useful device emulator:

[image]

Which is great, but **I'm not emulating anything:**

- All the options in Device are unticked
- All the options in Media are unticked
- All the options in Network are unselected
- All the options in Sensors are unticked

Clicking the 'reset' button also still shows the emulation bar.

**How can I turn  Chrome DevTools device emulator off when I am not using it?**

Comment: The answer in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308572/google-chrome-developer-tools-disable-black-emulation-options-ruler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308572/google-chrome-developer-tools-disable-black-emulation-options-ruler) is more clear.

Comment: Thanks @letian I have marked this as a duplicate.

Comment: They should have put it somewhere else, to make it more intuitive, because many people ,as I see, have problems finding it.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Open Developer Tools and click the "phone" icon - upper left corner.  This toggles the ruler on and off.

[image: Toggle device toolbar screenshot]

Comment: what do I do if there is no phone icon? it's vanished!

Comment: It says "toggle device toolbar" on my CHrome

Comment: Thank you! I must have clicked that button by accident, because I've been wondering what those borders were for MONTHS. Shrinking the page content was the straw that broke my camel's back.

Comment: Just added a screenshot from Chrome in Windows. I was trying to press the select elements button and must have unknowingly clicked that button too thinking I hit some stray keyboard combo I was unaware of.

Comment: The **UX crime** the Googlies are committing here is that a button on ONE screen controls the layout of ANOTHER screen.

Comment: That feeling when you run into this issue and found you already upvoted this over 2 years ago.  :-/

Comment: Such a UI fail. Been wondering about this for months. OK, I'm a casual user, I admit, so I waited to google this and find this SO. But why can't they put "Turn off device toolbar" by the control(s) for the device toolbar, @Google Chrome?!

Answer (score 21):

You can also use the keyboard shortcut.

| OS | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | `Shift + Enter` or `Ctrl + Shift + M` |
| Mac | `Cmd + Shift + M` |

Comment: i don't know why i didn't think to just try Shift-Enter, a lot of apps do full-screen/windowed toggle that way. anyway, this is way better than having to click an obscure tiny button that doesn't even catch your eye. thank you for posting it!