# How to get rid of the new chrome devtools rulers?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I updated chrome and when i open up devtools i see this.

[image: chrome new devtools rulers]

How can i get rid of the rulers (the dark part in the upper and right side)? It takes a lot of space and i have a little 13.3" screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Developer Tools - disable black emulation options ruler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308572/google-chrome-developer-tools-disable-black-emulation-options-ruler)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd>; In the top left next to the spyglass icon is a blue device icon, click it to toggle *device mode*.

[image]

Or you can use the keyboard shortcut to toggle Device Mode:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>