# Chrome "Inspect" Rulers - Disable

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Since this morning, I've noticed this unpleasant change when I do "inspect" in chrome.

[image: wtf]

I do not like any of that, and would love to know how to turn this "feature" off. I like the old subtle pure inspect mode, wtihıut any of the additional accessories that change the pagefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this very closed [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311819/868401), where you can disable this feature by clicking on the "Device Mode" button.

Comment: Oh thank you, I would come across that answer if I knew the correct terms to search for :)